# Html.RenderAction throws a TextWriter Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to using MVC. In my master page, I have the following code

```
var strAppThemes = <%= Html.RenderAction("PickupThemes", "Header") %>;
```

and my HeaderController is defined as below:

```
public class HeaderController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(PickupThemes());
    }

    public string PickupThemes()
    {
         return "Hello Lavanya Deepak!";
    }
}
```

and when I browse the aspx page which is deriving from this master page using that header, it throws the following error

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Line 18:            var strAppThemes = <%=
>   Html.RenderAction("PickupThemes", "Header") %>;

Where am I erring out?

Comment: It's hard to tell what "var strAppThemes" is. Is it supposed to be C# code, or are you trying to output some javascript?

Comment: var strAppThemes =

line is a JavaScript. The one within ASP-styled brackets is server-side code. I want the value of the same assigned to the javascript variable.

Comment: Trying using <% instead of <%=. See here for more info http://www.danielroot.info/2009/04/quick-aspnet-mvc-tip-double-check-html.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type is actually still an ActionResult, just an ActionResult of Content. Like below.

```
public ActionResult PickupThemese() {
    return Content("Hello Lavanya Deepak!");
}
```

Comment: No. It still shouts with the same error message. My controller definition is now as below:

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return (Content("Hello Lavanya Deepak"));
        }

Comment: I handled a different route now. Instead of using <% syntax now I am ajaxing the request to controller/method and capturing the output.

Comment: Glad I was of some kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

I handled a different route now. Instead of using <% syntax now I am ajaxing the request to controller/method and capturing the output.

--based on Tom's suggestion.

Not sure if this is the best method because it is going to seed an extra http request. If some one could shed light on why Line 18: var strAppThemes = <%= Html.RenderAction("PickupThemes", "Header") %>; is not working it would be great.